# Помогите пожалуйста! Я пробую создать случайный список состоящий из случайного количества элементов, но программатор выдаёт странную ошибку. Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import random
import numpy
N = random.randint(1, 10000)
spam = list(range(1, N + 1))
n = [spam]
K = random.randint(1, 100)
spam1 = list(range(1, K + 1))
k = [spam1]
b = []
numpy.random.randint(1, 2 * 10 ^ 9, n).tolist()
print(n)
print(k)
print(b)
```

ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/DX1/PycharmProjects/pythonProject1/main.py", line 10, in <module>
    numpy.random.randint(1, 2 * 10 ^ 9, n).tolist()
  File "mtrand.pyx", line 746, in numpy.random.mtrand.RandomState.randint
  File "_bounded_integers.pyx", line 1320, in numpy.random._bounded_integers._rand_int32
TypeError: 'list' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

Comment: Какой еще программатор?

Comment: Возможно я ошибаюсь насчет numpy но для чего у Вас эта строка? Она же вроде просто есть но не используется..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
spam = list(range(1, N + 1))
n = [spam]
...
numpy.random.randint(1, 2 * 10 ^ 9, n).tolist()
```

Итак, что у вас в переменных, и что требует функция `randint`:

- `spam` - список (list)
- `n` - список в списке
- третий параметр функции `randint` - это `size`, т.е. размер создаваемого случайного массива, либо список размеров, если это многомерный массив

Так вот, `randint` не понимает, как ему интерпретировать *список в списке* в данном случае. Если убрать одну вложенность и оставить просто список, то будет чуть лучше, но всё-равно скорее всего будет ошибка типа такой:

```
n = spam
...
ValueError: maximum supported dimension for an ndarray is 32, found 1866
```

Ну то есть максимум в `size` может быть 32 значения, и это будет 32-мерный массив, а если передать более длинный список размеров, то всё-равно будет ошибка, хотя и другая.

Так что вы сначала определитесь - что вы вообще делаете. Обычно нужен всё-таки одномерный массив и тогда в `n` должно быть число, а не список. Может вы там имели в виду `N`, а не `n`, например? Такой код выполняется без ошибки, хотя вы никуда результат и не присваиваете:

```
numpy.random.randint(1, 2 * 10 ^ 9, N).tolist()
```